# Java path on Windows hardcoded in my shell script on Linux, need to make it more flexible

Tags: java, bash, salt-stack

I am building a shell script on a Salt Master and trying to pull software versions on various servers which have minions installed. One command I am having issue with has the install path for both WebLogic and Java hardcoded and I need to make that path more flexible so that when an upgrade to WebLogic or Java is done (and the path changes) I won't have to go into my script and manually change the path. Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Here is an example:

```
salt -E hostname cmd.run "d: & cd '\bea\wlserver_12.1\server\lib\ & d:\Java\64\jdk1.7.0_91\bin\java -cp weblogic.jar weblogic.version"
```

Comment: Can't you use $JAVA_HOME ?

Comment: how would you recommend handling the $ within bash?